# Prove that a expression is not Integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

Let $k > 10$ an integer and $0 \leq x \leq k-4$ an integer and even, defined as

$$x_1= k-4  - \frac{(3k - 2)}{\sqrt{\left(4k - 3\right)}}$$

I need to prove that $x_1$ is not an integer, I have done a few tries, but it still fails. I count on your help! Thanks!

Comment: For $\sqrt{4k-3}$ to be rational then $4k-3$ must be a perfect square.  Let $4k -3 = M^2$ The $\frac 34(4k-3)=3k-\frac 94=(3k-2)-\frac 14$ so $3k-2=\frac 34(4k-2)+\frac 14=\frac 34M^2 + \frac 14$.   So $\frac {3k-2}{\sqrt{4k-3}}=\frac {\frac 34M^2+\frac 14}M=\frac 34M +\frac 1{4M}$ which can not be an integer if $M> 1$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $4k-3$ to be a square, $k$ must be odd (equal to $2n+1$ for some integer $n$), since otherwise, $4k-3\equiv5\bmod8$. So we can rewrite as $$2n-3-\frac{6n+1}{\sqrt{8n+1}}$$ This implies $n$ is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number#Explicit_formulas). In other words, there is some $m$ integer such that $n=0.5m(m+1)$. Substituting again, we get $$m^2+m-3-\frac{3m^2+3m+1}{2m+1}$$This can be written as $$m^2-\frac m2-\frac{15}4-\frac1{8m+4}$$

When $m=0$, $k=1$, so $m=0$ is not permitted. So, $\left\vert\frac1{8m+4}\right\vert<\frac14$. So, $-\frac72>-\frac{15}4-\frac1{8m+4}>3$, which implies that the expression is non-integral.